# Haskell safe-money example

Tags: haskell

This great author thoroughly convinced me to use `safe-money` via their well written blog post:

https://ren.zone/articles/safe-money

But trying examples in GHCi and trying various import statements, I cannot get it to work, even re-typing the exact samples from the blog post:

```
Prelude> :m Data.Ratio

Prelude Data.Ratio> 1 % 5
1 % 5

...

Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text> :m +Money

Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> :t dense
dense :: Rational -> Maybe (Dense currency)

Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> let y = 5 :: Integer
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> :t y
y :: Integer
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> y % 100
1 % 20
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> :t it
it :: Ratio Integer
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> let z = y % 100
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> :t z
z :: Ratio Integer
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> dense z

<interactive>:30:1: error:
    • No instance for (GHC.TypeLits.KnownSymbol currency0)
        arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> fromRational z
5.0e-2
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> :t it
it :: Fractional a => a

Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> fromRational z :: Dense "USD"

<interactive>:35:25: error:
    Illegal type: ‘"USD"’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money> 'fromRational' z :: Dense "USD"

<interactive>:36:1: error:
    • Syntax error on 'fromRational'
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    • In the Template Haskell quotation 'fromRational'

<interactive>:36:27: error:
    Illegal type: ‘"USD"’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
Prelude Data.Ratio Data.Text Money>  'fromRational' (341 % 100) :: Dense "USD"

<interactive>:37:2: error:
    • Syntax error on 'fromRational'
      Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell or TemplateHaskellQuotes
    • In the Template Haskell quotation 'fromRational'

<interactive>:37:38: error:
    Illegal type: ‘"USD"’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
```

I wish intelligent authors like this would be also practical, and include the step zero basics for beginner to intermediate haskellers.

The *ackage pages and github are also bare. Can anyone provide a working example of using `safe-money` here? I am surely spoiled by full examples in the yesod documentation.

I believe the package is this:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-money

Comment: Try `:set -XDataKinds` at the beginning of the session.

Comment: Also I have no idea what's going on with the quotes in `'fromRational' (341 % 100)`.  Not valid in any Haskell universe I know of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [luqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33796/luqui) commented, you need to enable the `DataKinds` extension.

You can enable this extension in a file with

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
```

You can enable this in GHCi with

```
:set -XDataKinds
```

The error message provided in GHCi should have been a good hint that you need to enable that extension.

> Illegal type: ‘"USD"’ Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds

It may help you to see more usage examples by browsing search results here: https://github.com/search?q=import+Money+dense+language%3Ahaskell&type=Code